# Generating the CSR using BouncyCastle API

Tags: java, security, certificate, bouncycastle

I am new to the security side of Java and stumbled across this library called BouncyCastle. But the examples that they provide and the ones out on the internet ask to use

```
return new PKCS10CertificationRequest("SHA256withRSA", new X500Principal(
    "CN=Requested Test Certificate"), pair.getPublic(), null, pair.getPrivate()
```

But when I use `PKCS10CertificationRequest`, it looks like it is deprecated. So I started looking at another method where I use `CertificationRequest` class. But I am really confused, the constructor does not take the same parameters instead it takes `CertificationRequestInfo` class which I am not sure how to fill up.

```
CertificationRequest request = new CertificationRequest(...);
```

It would be awesome if someone could help me figure out how to make a CSR so that I can send it to the server for getting it signed.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With the recent versions of BouncyCastle it is recommended to create the CSR using the `org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder` class.

You can use this code snipppet:

```
KeyPair pair = generateKeyPair();
PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder p10Builder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
    new X500Principal("CN=Requested Test Certificate"), pair.getPublic());
JcaContentSignerBuilder csBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA");
ContentSigner signer = csBuilder.build(pair.getPrivate());
PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = p10Builder.build(signer);
```

Comment: Thanks .. How do I print the CSR?

Comment: I got it .. did it with the help of PEMWriter class .. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For new code I'd suggest using JcaPEMWriter instead of PEMWriter.  Same interface but PEMWriter is now deprecated.

Comment: How can this be done with smartcard? Since the private key is on the card itself?

Comment: In that case the signature of the PKCS#10 request is performed by the smartcard.

Comment: @Jcs how can I pass the other information in csr generation like organisation unit, location, state , country , validity etc. ?

Comment: @VikramSinghShekhawat you can add these information in the X500Principal. For instance new X500Principal("CN=Requested Test Certificate, O=Test Inc, C=US")

Comment: For those looking for a maven/gradle package containing these classes: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15to18

Answer (score 3):

It's really simmilar to Jcs's answer, it is just a little bit supplemented.

Dont forget to add:

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

And the csr generate:

```
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(4096);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    
    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder p10Builder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
            new X500Principal("OU=Try, C=US## Heading ##"), keyPair.getPublic());

    JcaContentSignerBuilder csBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA");
    ContentSigner signer = csBuilder.build(keyPair.getPrivate());
    PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = p10Builder.build(signer);

    JcaPEMWriter jcaPEMWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(new FileWriter("cert/test.csr"));
    jcaPEMWriter.writeObject(csr);
    jcaPEMWriter.close();
```

I think a useful [link](http://Usefull%20link:%20https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter)