# EmailAddress in x500name for CSR? BOUNCY 1.54

Tags: bouncycastle, csr

I would like to add EmailAddress to my PKCS10 CSR:

```
        .addRDN( BCStrictStyle.EmailAddress, emailAddr )
```

Why does the Bouncy/Spongey spec say the following?:

> org.spongycastle.asn1.x500.style.BCStyle public static final
>   org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier EmailAddress Email address
>   (RSA PKCS#9 extension) - IA5String. Note: if you're trying to be ultra
>   orthodox, don't use this! It shouldn't be in here.

Is there something "wrong" w/ adding the EmailAddr to the x500name as part of a CSR?

If there is, then how should I properly add the EmailAddr to my CSR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the warning is that the latest X.509 specifications require mail addresses to be put in the subjectAlternativeName extension.

Quote from [RFC5280](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt):

> Legacy implementations exist where an electronic mail address is
>      embedded in the subject distinguished name as an emailAddress
>      attribute [RFC2985].  The attribute value for emailAddress is of type
>      IA5String to permit inclusion of the character '@', which is not part
>      of the PrintableString character set.  emailAddress attribute values
>      are not case-sensitive (e.g., "subscriber@example.com" is the same as
>      "SUBSCRIBER@EXAMPLE.COM").
>
> Conforming implementations generating new certificates with
>      electronic mail addresses MUST use the rfc822Name in the subject
>      alternative name extension (Section 4.2.1.6) to describe such
>      identities.  Simultaneous inclusion of the emailAddress attribute in
>      the subject distinguished name to support legacy implementations is
>      deprecated but permitted.

As you are creating a CSR and not a certificate, I wouldn't worry much about it. Few CAs can (or rather want to) process extensions in CSRs anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Omikron's answer: I create an x500name for our own spec's:

```
static private X500Name getX500Name(){
    final String testPostalCode = "94602-4105";
    return new X500NameBuilder( BCStrictStyle.INSTANCE )
            .addRDN( BCStyle.CN, Alias )
            //.addRDN( BCStrictStyle.EmailAddress, emailAddr )
            .addRDN( BCStrictStyle.POSTAL_CODE, testPostalCode )
            .addRDN( BCStrictStyle.SERIALNUMBER, deviceID )
            .addRDN( BCStrictStyle.C, deviceID )
            .build();
}//getX500Name
```

and I put the email addr into the extension:

```
//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376502(v=vs.85).aspx
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532912/generating-the-csr-using-bouncycastle-api
// http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation#X.509PublicKeyCertificateandCertificationRequestGeneration-SubjectAlternativeName
static public PKCS10CertificationRequest genCSR(){
    KeyPair pair = getKeyPair();
    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder p10Builder;
    ContentSigner signer;

    try{
        GeneralNames subjectAltName = new GeneralNames(
                new GeneralName(GeneralName.rfc822Name, emailAddr));

        PublicKey publicKey = getKeyStore().getCertificate( certKeyAlias ).getPublicKey();
        p10Builder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
                getX500Name()
                , publicKey )
                .addAttribute(Extension.subjectAlternativeName, new DEROctetString( subjectAltName)   )
                .setLeaveOffEmptyAttributes(true)

        ;

        JcaContentSignerBuilder csBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder( SHA256withECDSA );

        signer = csBuilder.build( pair.getPrivate() );
    }catch ( KeyStoreException | OperatorCreationException| IOException X ){
        pkException CRYPTOERR = new pkException( pkErrCode.CRYPTO ).set( "registrations err", X );
        mLog.error( CRYPTOERR.toString() );
        throw CRYPTOERR;
    }

    PKCS10CertificationRequest CSR = p10Builder.build( signer );
    return CSR;
}//genCSR
```